# How to check empty table in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables top1 and top2 .First I want to check top1 is empty or not.If top1 is not empty then truncate top2 and insert data from top1. Otherwise dont do any action .

```
CASE
WHEN top1 is not empty THEN
 Truncate top2
  Insert from Top1

END case
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` if this return 0 means your table is empty.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table)`...

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should do the trick.
Provided both of the tables have the same structure....

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM top1) THEN
  TRUNCATE TABLE Top2;
  INSERT INTO top2 SELECT * FROM top1;
END IF;
```

Comment: I reallly cannot see what would not work about it.
Perhaps you could supply details of the error?